# VHDL: recursive n bit comparator

Tags: recursion, vhdl

I have to create a n bit comparator (under respect of n = 2**k) in VHDL with recursion. Since the necassary chapter is taken after the christmasbreak, I have no lecture notes. My idea was using the generic statement like this:.
I thought I could use the generic statement, like this:

```
entity comperator is
    generic (k: integer := 0);
    port(a, b: std_logic_vector(2**k-1 downto 0);
         c: out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0));
end;

architecture recursive of comperator is 
  signal e,d: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin
    p2: if k /= 0 generate
      d1 : entity comperator
           port map (a(2**k-1 downto 2**(k-1)), b(2**k-1 downto 2**(k-1)), d);
```

I made with testbench a simulation but I got strange error reports, something like this:
"sem_parenthesis_name: cannot handle IIR_KIND_COMPONENT_INSTANTIATION_STATEMENT (design.vhd:19:11)"

If you need the hole code:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2RuY

I have no idea why the code doesn't work. Has anyone an idea?

Greedings,
What's in the box

Comment: Provide a [mcve] in the question itself.  `k` is a positive subtype of integer and 0 is not a positive value. Also note that `d1` and `d2` are implicitly declared labels denoting entity instantiations which can't be indexed or sliced (in the concurrent assignment statements, the first of which is decorated with the label `d3`). You can download or build a newer version of [tag:ghdl] which may provide more meaningful error messages. ghdl-0.35 was released on December 14, 2017. Re: "Hellos" stackoverflow isn't actually a social network, rather a formatted programming question and answer site.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, I fixded the noted problems, but my code still doesn't work. Is my basic idea of recursion in VHDL correct?
Thank's for the feedback, I'll better in the next post.

Comment: Providea [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the mistake, now it works. If someone has the same or similar problem, here is the link to the working source code:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2RuY

Comment: A question and answer without the ability for future readers to validate against their own problem isn't useful. Note EDAplayground links are frangible, they will not persist over time.  Further the testbench is neither complete nor valid VHDL.